# Importing modules in Python and __init__.py

Tags: python, module, import

I have been reading about the function of `__init__.py` file. It is said that we need an empty `__init__.py` file in the folder which contains modules, so that these modules can be imported. However, I tried adding a folder path to PYTHONPATH (Environment Variable in Windows 7). Although this folder does not contain an `__init__.py` file, I can still import the modules from that folder. Could you please explain how these modules can be imported without the existence of an `__init__.py`?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`__init__.py` turns a folder into a [package](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#packages). This is useful to create a sort of hierarchy of modules, where you can have import-statements like this:

```
import mymodule.cool.stuff
```

This is not possible without packages.

Comment: Ok, suppose there is a folder: "A". And "A" has an `__init__.py`. But "A" is not in the PYTHONPATH. Can I import a module from "A" folder? Does Python search all folders in my computer to know if they have "`__init__.py`"s in them? I mean how does python know the path to "A"?

Comment: @steve: You still have to add the path to the package to your `PYTHONPATH`. Python does not search your entire computer for folders containing `__init__.py`.

Answer (score 10):

If a directory (folder) contains a `__init__.py` file then it becomes a *package*.  What you thought you read was not strictly correct, as you found.  A package can be imported as if it was a module by itself, and any code in `__init__.py` is run, although it is often empty.  Packages are a way of grouping multiple modules together, and you can load them using:

```
import package-name.module-name
```

Packages can also be nested, and often are.  Look in the Lib directory under your Python software directory for many examples.

Answer (score 9):

The difference between **having _*init*_.py** and **not having** one in your module directory is:

When you **have** `__init__.py` (blank one), you can import the module using

```
from dirname import MyModule
```

But when you **dont have** _*init*_.py at all, you cannot import the module without adding the path till that module to PYTHONPATH. **In this case** `from dirname import MyModule` **FAILS**, or reports error.

**# Structure of directory/Module without _*init*_.py**

```
[root@Machine python]# cd NoInitModule/
[root@Machine NoInitModule]# pwd
/python/NoInitModule
[root@Machine NoInitModule]# ls -l
total 4
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 44 Jan 16 07:02 ModuleX.py
```

**# Structure of directory/Module with _*init*_.py**

```
[root@Machine NoInitModule]# cd ../InitModule/
[root@Machine InitModule]# ls -l
total 4
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  0 Jan 16 07:13 __init__.py
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 49 Jan 16 07:12 ModuleY.py
[root@Machine InitModule]#
```

**Examples:**

**# NO _*init*_.py, from dir import module statement  - DOESN'T WORK**

```
[root@Machine python]# cat impomod.py
from NoInitModule import ModuleX

ModuleX.printBye()

[root@Machine python]# python impomod.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "impomod.py", line 7, in <module>
    from NoInitModule import ModuleX
ImportError: No module named NoInitModule
[root@Machine python]#
```

**# NO _*init*_.py, import statement  - DOESN'T WORK**

```
[root@Machine python]# vim impomod.py
[root@Machine python]# cat impomod.py
#from NoInitModule import ModuleX
import ModuleX

ModuleX.printBye()
[root@Machine python]# python impomod.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "impomod.py", line 8, in <module>
    import ModuleX
ImportError: No module named ModuleX
[root@Machine python]#
```

**# NO _*init*_.py, INSERT path in PYTHONPATH, import module statement after inserting path - WORKS**

```
[root@Machine python]# vim impomod.py
[root@Machine python]# cat impomod.py
import sys
sys.path.append('/python/NoInitModule')
print sys.path

import ModuleX
ModuleX.printBye()

[root@Machine python]# python impomod.py
Bye from Module X with no __init__.py
[root@Machine python]#
```

**# HAVING _*init*_.py, No INSERT of path, from dir import module statement - WORKS**

```
[root@Machine python]# cat impXmod.py
import sys
from InitModule import ModuleY
ModuleY.printSeeU()
[root@Machine python]#

[root@Machine python]# python impXmod.py
See you from Module Y having __init__.py
```

**# HAVING _*init*_.py, No INSERT of path, import module statement - DOESN'T WORK**

```
[root@Machine python]# vim impXmod.py
[root@Machine python]# cat impXmod.py
import sys
#from InitModule import ModuleY
import ModuleY
ModuleY.printSeeU()

[root@Machine python]# python impXmod.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "impXmod.py", line 3, in <module>
    import ModuleY
ImportError: No module named ModuleY
```

Ofcourse, subfolders issue can be added to this

Answer (score 6):

Yes, this works, as you can tell.  The reason for the empty `__init__.py` file is to mark **sub-folders** as folders containing modules.

So a folder in PYTHONPATH is ok to have modules in it, but any subfolders of those folders have to have a `__init__.py` file in them to be able to import modules from them.

Comment: `__init__.py` does not *have* to be empty.

Comment: @Ignacio: Neither does it have to have something in it if its only task is to mark a folder as having modules.  The OP mentioned empty `__init__.py` files.