# Access modules from test file

Tags: python, path

Here is my file structure that I am working with for my application. My problem is that I cannot get my test_ctd.py file to see my ctd.py file.

Here is my directory structure

```
FileParser
--Parsers
----ctd.py
--tests
----__init__.py
----test_ctd.py
--parse.py
```

I never used an **init**.py file and am struggling to understand it, but here is my attempt at adding ctd.py to my path.

```
import sys
import os.path
d = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath('../../')))

from Parsers import ctd
```

Also I do not have any code in my parse.py file, but I will be using that to initiate the program.  Would I need a    **init** file for that as well so I can import the files from the Parsers folder?

Any help on how to access my files from within this program structure would be appreciated.  Eventually it will be running on a web server, not sure if that makes a difference or not...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Parsers` and `FileParser` must contain `__init__.py` if you want to import something from `ctd.py`. See [Importing modules in Python and __init__.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5910379/importing-modules-in-python-and-init-py).

Then, you can import `ctd.py` from your tests scripts by doing relative imports like `from ..Parsers import ctd` or by adding `FileParser` to `sys.path` and using `from Parsers import ctd`.

Or, add the directory containing `FileParser` to `sys.path` and use `from FileParser.Parsers import ctd`.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Move the `__init__.py` file into `Parsers` and add the directory `FileParser` as absolute path to your PYTHONPATH. For example with `sys.path.append('full/path/to/FileParser')`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure Python is actually looking in the right places. You can do this by modifying your `PYTHONPATH` environment variable to include places where Python packages are found (such as this directory). You'll also need an `__init__.py` file, to mark the directory as a Python package.

Or, the cheap, hacky way is by modifying `sys.path`.

```
import sys
import os
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)), 'Parsers'))
import cdt
```