# Python to specify which module to import from if there are duplicate module names?

Tags: python

Related to: [Import a module from a relative path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279237/import-a-module-from-a-relative-path)

```
dirA/
    A.py
    B.py
dirB/
    B.py

A.py
import B

# do blah
```

I want A to import B.

How do i specify A to import B from dirB instead of dirA since both dirs have B.py?

Comment: What do you mean by "I want A to import B".  There are two Bs.  Which B do you want A to import?  Why do you have `B.py` in `dirA` if you don't want A to import it?

Comment: exactly. thats the problem since there are two. Its a version control thing in my software. there are cases where A (which is a wrapper) needs import from previous version B.py located in different tree in the file system

Comment: I think you should explain your actual situation.  You probably need to rethink your strategy for this problem.  Trying to import one of multiple identically-named files in separate directories that are not packages is going to lead to very confusing code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think what you're asking for is how to load a module directly from a directory.

```
import imp

moduleB = imp.load_source('moduleB', '/ModuleBPath/B.py')
moduleB.MyClass()
```

Comment: Am not aware of this. interesting.. :)

Answer (score 2):

u can use like below :-

```
from A import B
from B import B as B1
```

and continue to use.

Comment: i think this is assumping that dirA and dirB has __init__.py. what if they dont?

Comment: Please refer this stack overflow link for your question >> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5910379/importing-modules-in-python-and-init-py

Answer (score 1):

You could try such variant:

```
from ..dirB import B
```