# Import from subfolder with duplicate filenames

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following directory structure:

```
.
|
|--- __init__.py
|--- main.py
|--- FolderA
|    |
|    |--- __init__.py
|    |--- scriptA.py
|    |--- config.py
|--- FolderB
     |
     |--- __init__.py
     |--- scriptB.py
     |--- config.py
```

scriptA.py:

```
import config
print(config.something)
```

scriptB.py:

```
import config
print(config.something)
```

config.py (FolderA):

```
something = "A"
```

config.py (FolderB):

```
something = "B"
```

`scriptA.py` should import the `config.py` from `FolderA`, and `scriptB.py` the `config.py` from `FolderB`.

Now, in `main.py` I would like to directly import both scripts and both configs. All `.py` files should be executed directly in their respective location, i.e. `scriptA` should run in `FolderA`, and `main.py` in `.`

main.py:

```
import sys, os
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'FolderA'))
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'FolderB'))

from FolderA import scriptA #runs scriptA

from FolderB import scriptB #runs scriptB
```

Output:

```
"A"
"A" #should be "B"
```

For some reason, the config from FolderB is not used in scriptB

I have read [this resource](https://chrisyeh96.github.io/2017/08/08/definitive-guide-python-imports.html), which tells me that this is not directly possible in python3. However, is there a **reasonable workaround** so that I can fully import and use all scripts and configs in `main.py` (e.g. `import FolderA.config as configA`) *and* ensure that the scripts are executable in their respective folders as well?

**Edit:**

I have added a working main.py that clearly shows the problem.

Comment: So is `main.py` just responsible for launching `scriptA.py` and `scriptB.py`?  You could always defer your imports and do something a bit more dynamic, e.g. `for group in ['A', 'B']: os.chdir(os.path.join(root, f'Folder{group}')); importlib.import_module(f'script{group}'); ...`

Comment: IMO it would be far simpler to just rename `FolderA/config.py` to `configA.py` and similarly for `FolderB/config.py`. Would you really want to maintain such complicated imports 6 months down the line?

Comment: @rdas Of course I could rename the files, but the point of the question was if this can be achieved without renaming them.

Comment: @mtoller And my point was that even if it can, it's probably not worth doing it.

Comment: @0x5453 importlib seems like a good option, but your solution gives ` File "/./FolderA/scriptA.py", line 1, in <module>
    from config import config
ImportError: cannot import name 'config' from 'config' `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem using `imp.load_source` as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28353249/6156480):

main.py:

```
from imp import load_source

config=load_source('config','/home/mtoller/mre/FolderA/config.py')
from FolderA import scriptA

config=load_source('config','/home/mtoller/mre/FolderB/config.py')
from FolderB import scriptB
```

output:

```
 "A"
 "B"
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I missunderstood something but it should work with:

```
import FolderA
import FolderB

print(FolderA.scriptA.config.something)
```

Or you could execute a funtion called `foo` from scriptA.py: `FolderA.scriptA.foo()`

Comment: this suggestion gives me `AttributeError: module 'FolderA' has no attribute 'config'` in the mre

Comment: Oh yeah sorry, I edited the answer. Does this work properly?

Comment: no, this gives `AttributeError: module 'FolderA' has no attribute 'scriptA'`

Comment: You are right, my answer was not a solution for your problem, sorry