# Python 2.7 protobuf .py file generation issue

Tags: python, python-2.7, protocol-buffers

I am following this guide (https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/pythontutorial) and using the exact sample of addressbook.proto.

Here is the content of generated addressbook_pb2.py file, question is where is the definition of class `Person`, `PhoneNumber` and `AddressBook`? I see the sample code of the guide refer them as classes.

**Here is the sample code I refer to,**

```
import addressbook_pb2
person = addressbook_pb2.Person()
person.id = 1234
person.name = "John Doe"
person.email = "jdoe@example.com"
phone = person.phone.add()
phone.number = "555-4321"
phone.type = addressbook_pb2.Person.HOME
```

Another quick question is, where should I put file addressbook_pb2.py, so that my other python file could refer it to use `Person`, `PhoneNumber` and `AddressBook` classes?

**Here is the automated generated file addressbook_pb2.py,**

```
# Generated by the protocol buffer compiler.  DO NOT EDIT!
# source: addressbook.proto

import sys
_b=sys.version_info[0]<3 and (lambda x:x) or (lambda x:x.encode('latin1'))
from google.protobuf import descriptor as _descriptor
from google.protobuf import message as _message
from google.protobuf import reflection as _reflection
from google.protobuf import symbol_database as _symbol_database
from google.protobuf import descriptor_pb2
# @@protoc_insertion_point(imports)

_sym_db = _symbol_database.Default()




DESCRIPTOR = _descriptor.FileDescriptor(
  name='addressbook.proto',
  package='tutorial',
  syntax='proto2',
  serialized_pb=_b('\n\x11\x61\x64\x64ressbook.proto\x12\x08tutorial\"\xda\x01\n\x06Person\x12\x0c\n\x04name\x18\x01 \x02(\t\x12\n\n\x02id\x18\x02 \x02(\x05\x12\r\n\x05\x65mail\x18\x03 \x01(\t\x12+\n\x05phone\x18\x04 \x03(\x0b\x32\x1c.tutorial.Person.PhoneNumber\x1aM\n\x0bPhoneNumber\x12\x0e\n\x06number\x18\x01 \x02(\t\x12.\n\x04type\x18\x02 \x01(\x0e\x32\x1a.tutorial.Person.PhoneType:\x04HOME\"+\n\tPhoneType\x12\n\n\x06MOBILE\x10\x00\x12\x08\n\x04HOME\x10\x01\x12\x08\n\x04WORK\x10\x02\"/\n\x0b\x41\x64\x64ressBook\x12 \n\x06person\x18\x01 \x03(\x0b\x32\x10.tutorial.Person')
)
_sym_db.RegisterFileDescriptor(DESCRIPTOR)



_PERSON_PHONETYPE = _descriptor.EnumDescriptor(
  name='PhoneType',
  full_name='tutorial.Person.PhoneType',
  filename=None,
  file=DESCRIPTOR,
  values=[
    _descriptor.EnumValueDescriptor(
      name='MOBILE', index=0, number=0,
      options=None,
      type=None),
    _descriptor.EnumValueDescriptor(
      name='HOME', index=1, number=1,
      options=None,
      type=None),
    _descriptor.EnumValueDescriptor(
      name='WORK', index=2, number=2,
      options=None,
      type=None),
  ],
  containing_type=None,
  options=None,
  serialized_start=207,
  serialized_end=250,
)
_sym_db.RegisterEnumDescriptor(_PERSON_PHONETYPE)


_PERSON_PHONENUMBER = _descriptor.Descriptor(
  name='PhoneNumber',
  full_name='tutorial.Person.PhoneNumber',
  filename=None,
  file=DESCRIPTOR,
  containing_type=None,
  fields=[
    _descriptor.FieldDescriptor(
      name='number', full_name='tutorial.Person.PhoneNumber.number', index=0,
      number=1, type=9, cpp_type=9, label=2,
      has_default_value=False, default_value=_b("").decode('utf-8'),
      message_type=None, enum_type=None, containing_type=None,
      is_extension=False, extension_scope=None,
      options=None),
    _descriptor.FieldDescriptor(
      name='type', full_name='tutorial.Person.PhoneNumber.type', index=1,
      number=2, type=14, cpp_type=8, label=1,
      has_default_value=True, default_value=1,
      message_type=None, enum_type=None, containing_type=None,
      is_extension=False, extension_scope=None,
      options=None),
  ],
  extensions=[
  ],
  nested_types=[],
  enum_types=[
  ],
  options=None,
  is_extendable=False,
  syntax='proto2',
  extension_ranges=[],
  oneofs=[
  ],
  serialized_start=128,
  serialized_end=205,
)

_PERSON = _descriptor.Descriptor(
  name='Person',
  full_name='tutorial.Person',
  filename=None,
  file=DESCRIPTOR,
  containing_type=None,
  fields=[
    _descriptor.FieldDescriptor(
      name='name', full_name='tutorial.Person.name', index=0,
      number=1, type=9, cpp_type=9, label=2,
      has_default_value=False, default_value=_b("").decode('utf-8'),
      message_type=None, enum_type=None, containing_type=None,
      is_extension=False, extension_scope=None,
      options=None),
    _descriptor.FieldDescriptor(
      name='id', full_name='tutorial.Person.id', index=1,
      number=2, type=5, cpp_type=1, label=2,
      has_default_value=False, default_value=0,
      message_type=None, enum_type=None, containing_type=None,
      is_extension=False, extension_scope=None,
      options=None),
    _descriptor.FieldDescriptor(
      name='email', full_name='tutorial.Person.email', index=2,
      number=3, type=9, cpp_type=9, label=1,
      has_default_value=False, default_value=_b("").decode('utf-8'),
      message_type=None, enum_type=None, containing_type=None,
      is_extension=False, extension_scope=None,
      options=None),
    _descriptor.FieldDescriptor(
      name='phone', full_name='tutorial.Person.phone', index=3,
      number=4, type=11, cpp_type=10, label=3,
      has_default_value=False, default_value=[],
      message_type=None, enum_type=None, containing_type=None,
      is_extension=False, extension_scope=None,
      options=None),
  ],
  extensions=[
  ],
  nested_types=[_PERSON_PHONENUMBER, ],
  enum_types=[
    _PERSON_PHONETYPE,
  ],
  options=None,
  is_extendable=False,
  syntax='proto2',
  extension_ranges=[],
  oneofs=[
  ],
  serialized_start=32,
  serialized_end=250,
)


_ADDRESSBOOK = _descriptor.Descriptor(
  name='AddressBook',
  full_name='tutorial.AddressBook',
  filename=None,
  file=DESCRIPTOR,
  containing_type=None,
  fields=[
    _descriptor.FieldDescriptor(
      name='person', full_name='tutorial.AddressBook.person', index=0,
      number=1, type=11, cpp_type=10, label=3,
      has_default_value=False, default_value=[],
      message_type=None, enum_type=None, containing_type=None,
      is_extension=False, extension_scope=None,
      options=None),
  ],
  extensions=[
  ],
  nested_types=[],
  enum_types=[
  ],
  options=None,
  is_extendable=False,
  syntax='proto2',
  extension_ranges=[],
  oneofs=[
  ],
  serialized_start=252,
  serialized_end=299,
)

_PERSON_PHONENUMBER.fields_by_name['type'].enum_type = _PERSON_PHONETYPE
_PERSON_PHONENUMBER.containing_type = _PERSON
_PERSON.fields_by_name['phone'].message_type = _PERSON_PHONENUMBER
_PERSON_PHONETYPE.containing_type = _PERSON
_ADDRESSBOOK.fields_by_name['person'].message_type = _PERSON
DESCRIPTOR.message_types_by_name['Person'] = _PERSON
DESCRIPTOR.message_types_by_name['AddressBook'] = _ADDRESSBOOK

Person = _reflection.GeneratedProtocolMessageType('Person', (_message.Message,), dict(

  PhoneNumber = _reflection.GeneratedProtocolMessageType('PhoneNumber', (_message.Message,), dict(
    DESCRIPTOR = _PERSON_PHONENUMBER,
    __module__ = 'addressbook_pb2'
    # @@protoc_insertion_point(class_scope:tutorial.Person.PhoneNumber)
    ))
  ,
  DESCRIPTOR = _PERSON,
  __module__ = 'addressbook_pb2'
  # @@protoc_insertion_point(class_scope:tutorial.Person)
  ))
_sym_db.RegisterMessage(Person)
_sym_db.RegisterMessage(Person.PhoneNumber)

AddressBook = _reflection.GeneratedProtocolMessageType('AddressBook', (_message.Message,), dict(
  DESCRIPTOR = _ADDRESSBOOK,
  __module__ = 'addressbook_pb2'
  # @@protoc_insertion_point(class_scope:tutorial.AddressBook)
  ))
_sym_db.RegisterMessage(AddressBook)


# @@protoc_insertion_point(module_scope)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Python classes are generated dynamically at runtime.

Quoting from the documentation page that you have linked to:

> The important line in each class is **metaclass** =
>   reflection.GeneratedProtocolMessageType. While the details of how
>   Python metaclasses work is beyond the scope of this tutorial, you can
>   think of them as like a template for creating classes. At load time,
>   the GeneratedProtocolMessageType metaclass uses the specified
>   descriptors to create all the Python methods you need to work with
>   each message type and adds them to the relevant classes. You can then
>   use the fully-populated classes in your code.

More specifically the line:

```
Person = _reflection.GeneratedProtocolMessageType('Person', (_message.Message,), dict(...
```

creates the Person class in Python.

In Python, something like:

```
>>> Person = type('Person', (), {})
>>> Person
<class '__main__.Person'>
```

is same as defining a regular `Person` class. This is what is being used under the hood here.

You may want to look at the SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100003/what-is-a-metaclass-in-python) or this [blog entry](https://blog.ionelmc.ro/2015/02/09/understanding-python-metaclasses/),if you are not very familiar with the concept of metaclasses.

**Edited in reply to last comment**

I am not sure if I correctly understood your last remark but
If you want to use the `Person` class from `addressbook_pb2.py` in `foo.py`, 
you place  `addressbook_pb2.py` adjacent to `foo.py` and do the following import in `foo.py`:

```
from addressbook_pb2 import Person
```

Comment: Thanks tao, vote up and will try. Another quick question is, where should I put `addressbook_pb2.py` if I need to refer it (e.g. refer `Person`) in another python file in the same directory?

Comment: It is just another regular Python file and so you may put it anywhere in your application directory structure and then import it specifying the file directory hierarchy as in `import directory.path.to.your.file.addressbook_pb2.py`.  You may have to add a blank `__init__.py` file to the directory where you keep this file for Python to recognise it as a package

Comment: Thanks tao, vote up. In the code I posted for `addressbook_pb2.py`, it does not have any package definition, so, I should be safe to skip the step of add a blank `__init__.py` file?

Comment: The answer to this is a bit more lengthy so I would suggest you read this answer:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/21166205/2348704

Comment: Thanks tao, vote up, and for the addressbook_pb2.py I posted in my original post, for `Person`, it is in any package? I have the confusion since I see you refer `Person` by `Person = _reflection.GeneratedProtocolMessageType`, it seems `Person` is not in any packages from your code, but from the code `full_name='tutorial.Person'`, it seems it is in `tutorial` package?

Comment: edited my answer to post reply to your last question

Comment: Thanks tao for update, and vote up. I think you understand my question correctly. I am wondering for your code you `from addressbook_pb2`, and `addressbook_pb2` is a package name or? I have this confusion since I do not find a package called `addressbook_pb2` defined in protobuf compiled file. Thanks.

Comment: No addressbook_pb2 is not the package name, it is the filename(a file is called a module in Python). A Python package is simply a directory of Python module(s) (read files). Check this answer http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/111882/121746

Answer (score 1):

The `Person` class is defined in this line of your `addressbook_pb2.py`:

```
Person = _reflection.GeneratedProtocolMessageType('Person', (_message.Message,), dict( ... ) )
```

And similarly for the `AddressBook` class. Note that the `PhoneNumber` class you refer to is actually `Person.PhoneNumber`.

What is happening here? `GeneratedProtocolMessageType` is a *metaclass*.  A *metaclass* is a type whose instances are simple classes, and is invoked with the form:

```
metaclass(<class name>, <tuple of base classes for this new class>, <namespace of new class>)
```

As to where you should put `addressbook_pb2.py`, that depends entirely on how you are structuring your project.  Place it either somewhere on your `PYTHONPATH`, or beside your application.

Comment: Thanks donkopotamus, vote up and will try. Another quick question is, where should I put `addressbook_pb2.py` if I need to refer it (e.g. refer `Person`) in another python file in the same directory? Is there a simple way without rewrite `PYTHONPATH`?

Comment: If you are not using "packages" at all, simply put it beside your other modules.

Comment: Thanks donkopotamus, vote up for your reply, do you mean I should just put `addressbook_pb2.py` in the same directory as `foo.py`, suppose I want to use Person class defined in `addressbook_pb2.py` from `foo.py`?